# Create a new column based on a combination of columns + conditions + thresholds in r

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, multiple-columns, threshold

I have a problem with a piece of code, to start I share a dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("0002" ,"0002", "0005", "0005" ,"0009" ,"0009" ,"0018", "0018" ,"0039" ,"0039" , "0043" ,"0043", "0046", "0046" ,"0048" ,"0048"),
                 sex= c("F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", "M","F", "F",  "M", "M",  "M", "M", "F", "F"),
                 A1 = c( 1961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 1005.820 , 925.752 , 969.469  ,943.398 ,  965.292 , 1996.404 ,  967.047 ,  NA , 893.428 , 921.606 , 976.192 , 929.590 , 950.493),
                 B1 = c(998.988 , NA , 1998.680 , NA , 1020.560 ,  955.540 , 1911.606 , 964.039   ,  988.087 , 1902.367 , 959.338 ,1029.050 , 1987.374 ,1066.400  ,957.512 , 917.597),
                 C1 = c( 1987.140 , 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 969.469 , 943.398  ,936.034,  965.292 , 996.404 , 1920.610 , 967.047, 913.517 , 893.428 , 921.606 , 929.590  ,950.493), 
                 D1 = c( 1961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 1005.820 , 925.752 , 969.469  ,1943.398 ,  965.292 , 996.404 ,  967.047 ,  NA , 1893.428 , 921.606 , 976.192 , 929.590 , 950.493),
                 E1 = c(1006.330, 1028.070 ,  954.274 ,1005.910  ,949.969 , 992.820 ,934.407 , 948.913 ,    961.375  ,955.296 , 961.128  ,998.119 ,1009.110 , 994.891 ,1000.170  ,982.763),
                 G1= c(987.140 , 961.810 , 929.466 , 978.166, 969.469 , 943.398  ,936.034,  965.292 , 996.404 , 920.610 , 967.047, 913.517 , 893.428 , 921.606 , 1929.590  ,950.493),
                 A2 = c(NA , 977.146 , NA , 964.315 ,NA , 952.311 , NA , NA , 947.465 , 902.852 ,  NA  ,NA , 930.141 ,1007.790 , NA , 999.414),
                 B2 = c(1998.988 , NA , 1998.680 , NA , NA ,  955.540 , NA , 964.039   ,  988.087 , 1902.367 , NA ,1029.050 , NA ,1066.400  ,NA , 917.597),
                 C2 = c( NA , NA , NA , NA, 969.469 , NA  ,936.034,  965.292 , NA , 1920.610 , 967.047, NA , 1893.428 , 921.606 , 929.590  ,950.493), 
                 D2 = c( 961.810 , NA , 978.166, NA , 925.752 , NA  ,943.398 ,  1965.292 , NA ,  1967.047 ,  NA , 1893.428 , 921.606 , 976.192 , NA , 1950.493),
                 E2 = c(1006.330, 1028.070 ,  NA ,1005.910  ,949.969 , 992.820 ,1934.407 , 948.913 ,    961.375  ,955.296 , NA  ,998.119 ,NA , 994.891 ,1000.170  ,982.763),
                 G2= c(NA , 958.990 , 924.680 , 955.927 , NA , NA  ,973.348 , 984.392 , NA , NA , 995.368 , 1994.997 ,  979.454 , 952.605 ,NA , 956.507), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

To contextualize the problem: I have 2 sets of metrics defined at visit`1` (`A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,G1`) and the same metrics repeated at visit`2` (`A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,G2`)
To diagnose someone at visit 1, I use the following code:

```
cols <- 3:8
df$sex= as.factor(df$sex)
df %>% mutate(Diagnosis=ifelse(sex == "F" & (rowSums(df[cols] > 1004, na.rm = TRUE) >=3) ,'Yes',
                                      ifelse(sex == "M" & (rowSums(df[cols] > 986, na.rm = TRUE) >=3) ,'Yes','No')))-> df
```

This piece of code does what I want and it is perfectly fine! :)
As you can see, I have one threshold for female (1004) and one threshold for male (986). Based on the equation, when the patient has 3 or more metrics above the threshold gets a 'Yes' in the diagnosis.

Now, the problem comes with visit 2. In this case, the diagnosis has 4 options, the patient can be diagnosed as "ongoing", "resolved", "new onset" or "never" disease.

In theory, the solution should be as easy as apply this piece of code:

```
cols <- 9:14
df$sex= as.factor(df$sex)
df %>% mutate(Diagnosis=ifelse(sex == "F" & (rowSums(df[cols] > 1004, na.rm = TRUE) >=3) ,'Yes',
                                      ifelse(sex == "M" & (rowSums(df[cols] > 986, na.rm = TRUE) >=3) ,'Yes','No')))-> df
```

and then a really easy `ifelse` where were:

- if yes at visit 1 and yes at visit 2 = ongoing
- if yes at visit 1 and no at visit 2 = resolved
- if no at visit 1 and yes at visit 2 = new onset
- if no at visit 1 and no at visit 2 = never

However the situation is a bit more complex, with a new option called "NPA" (not possible to assess) as there two potential exceptions: as in order to make a reliable judgement, we need to see what happened with those metrics that were elevated. I create a simplified **examples** to ilustrate each of the exceptions:

A) For example this patient has C1, D1 and E1 elevated at visit 1, however, C2 is NA, therefore this patient at visit 2 would be an NPA

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("112"),
                 sex= c("F"),
                 A1 = c( 961.810),
                 B1 = c(998.988)
                 C1 = c( 1019.330)
                 D1 = c( 1046.0)
                 E1 = c(1006.330)
                 G1= c(987.140 ),
                 A2 = c(NA )
                 B2 = c(998.988),
                 C2 = c( NA ), 
                 D2 = c( 961.810),
                 E2 = c(1006.330),
                 G2= c(NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

B) In this case C1, D1 and E1 elevated at visit 1, C2 is NA, but A2 is elevated, so regardless to have C1 missing, this patient presents with a clear "yes" at visit 2, that together with a "yes" in visit 1, would be a "ongoing" case.

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("112"),
                 sex= c("F"),
                 A1 = c( 961.810),
                 B1 = c(998.988)
                 C1 = c( 1019.330)
                 D1 = c( 1046.0)
                 E1 = c(1006.330)
                 G1= c(987.140 ),
                 A2 = c(1800.810)
                 B2 = c(998.988),
                 C2 = c( NA ), 
                 D2 = c( 961.810),
                 E2 = c(1006.330),
                 G2= c(NA), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

How could I code this. Sorry I know this is a bit rumbling!
Thanks!

I attach the solution

[image]

Comment: Not strictly required, but are you truly limited to exactly two visits, or is your next problem how to generalize this for a third (and subsequent) visit?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the result you are expecting for your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a nice job communicating your logic in words; I just converted that into a big if else. See if this works for you:

(were you expecting this many `ongoing`?)

```
cols1 <- names(df)[3:8]
cols2 <- names(df)[9:14]

plogic <- function(x) {
  # Define threshold values for each sex
  thresh <- ifelse(df[x,"sex"] == "M", 986, ifelse(df[x,"sex"] == "F", 1004, print("no threshold specified")))
  # Test for conditions
  if(df[x,"C1"] > thresh & df[x,"D1"] > thresh & df[x,"E1"] > thresh & is.na(df[x,"C2"])) {
    return("NPA")
  }else if(df[x,"C1"] > thresh & df[x,"D1"] > thresh & df[x,"E1"] > thresh & df[x,"A2"] > thresh) {
    return("ongoing")
  }else if(length(df[x,cols1] > thresh) >= 3 & length(df[x,cols2] > thresh) >= 3){
    return("ongoing")
  }else if(length(df[x,cols1] > thresh) >= 3 & length(df[x,cols2] > thresh) < 3) {
    return("resolved")
  }else if(length(df[x,cols1] > thresh) < 3 & length(df[x,cols2] > thresh) >= 3) {
    return("new onset")
  }else if(length(df[x,cols1] > thresh) < 3 & length(df[x,cols2] > thresh) < 3){
    return("never")
  }else{
    return("error")
  }
}

sapply(1:nrow(df), plogic)
#>  [1] "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing"
#>  [8] "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing" "ongoing"
#> [15] "ongoing" "ongoing" "NPA"
Created on 2021-09-23 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!- this would work!  could you explain to me a bit more this two lines?   if(df[x,"C1"] > thresh & df[x,"D1"] > thresh & df[x,"E1"] > thresh & is.na(df[x,"C2"])) {
    return("NPA")
  }else if(df[x,"C1"] > thresh & df[x,"D1"] > thresh & df[x,"E1"] > thresh & df[x,"A2"] > thresh) {
    return("ongoing").    This is only a sample dataset and in the reality visit 1 and visit 2  have 19 columns each (sorry about that)

Comment: I guess what confuses me is why did you specify columns variables D, E C and A there, when the elevation can be in any column :) the conditions A and B were just examples...

Comment: I see, I thought Example A and B were very specific cases regarding particular responses that you wanted to account for. Sorry about that. It sounds like the correct approach needs to be more sensitive to the fate of individual responses. I'll comment again when I update my answer.

Comment: Hi @Lili, I spent some time thinking about this, and the result is a massively complex logic chain, that is hard to explain, understand, and is very fragile. Would it be possible to instead use a scoring system based on your logic. E.g., each elevated value receives a 1, a sum of 3 = ongoing. If so, how would you translate your NPA condition into a scoring system like this?